# Face error in install Django REST framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When I write: `pip install djangorestframework`

In CMD show me: `Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"H:\Full Stack\Django\Django_All\project1\env\Scripts\python.exe"  "H:\Full Stack\Django\Django_All\project1\studybud\env\Scripts\pip.exe" install djangorestframework': The system cannot find the file specified`

[image: Here the problem image]

Comment: Looks like a path problem.. can you do `python` and `pip` on their own?

Answer (score 0):

remove rest_framework from installed app and then run pip install djangorestframework and then add rest_framework in installed app.